Free abelian group functor preserves Kan fibration
Suppose, $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free abelian group functor from simplicial sets to simplicial abelian groups. Then does $\mathbb{Z}$ preserves Kan fibrations i.e. if $X \to Y$ is a Kan fibration between simplicial sets, then is the induced map $\mathbb{Z}(X) \to \mathbb{Z}(Y)$ a Kan fibration?
